# Calculating data parameters in pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I have the following pandas data frame:

code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A1': [0.1,0.5,3.0, 9.0], 'A2':[2.0,4.5,1.2,9.0],'Random 
data':[300,4500,800,900],'Random data2':[3000,450,80,90]})
```

output:

```
    A1  A2  Randomdata  Randomdata2
0   0.1 2.0    300            3000
1   0.5 4.5    4500           450
2   3.0 1.2    800            80
3   9.0 9.0    900            90
```

It is only showing A1 and A2 but it actually goes **from A1 to A30** of data.  I want to calculate the average and standard deviation for each row but only columns A1 to A30 (not including the columns Randomdata and Randomdata2) and add 2 new columns with the average and standard deviation like shown below.

```
     A1 A2  Randomdata  Randomdata2  Average   Stddev
0   0.1 2.0    300            3000
1   0.5 4.5    4500           450
2   3.0 1.2    800            80
3   9.0 9.0    900            90
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Preferred Approach**
Use `pd.DataFrame.filter`
Your choice for `regex` `pattern` can be as explicit as you'd like.  In this case, I specified that the column must start with `'A'` and have 1 or more digits afterwards.

```
d = df.filter(regex='^A\d+')
df.assign(Average=d.mean(1), Stddev=d.std(1))

    A1   A2  Random data  Random data2  Average    Stddev
0  0.1  2.0          300          3000     1.05  1.343503
1  0.5  4.5         4500           450     2.50  2.828427
2  3.0  1.2          800            80     2.10  1.272792
3  9.0  9.0          900            90     9.00  0.000000
```

---

**Alt 1**
This is trying too hard.

```
rnm = dict(mean='Average', std='Stddev')
df.join(df.T[df.columns.str.startswith('A')].agg(['mean', 'std']).T.rename(columns=rnm))

    A1   A2  Random data  Random data2  Average    Stddev
0  0.1  2.0          300          3000     1.05  1.343503
1  0.5  4.5         4500           450     2.50  2.828427
2  3.0  1.2          800            80     2.10  1.272792
3  9.0  9.0          900            90     9.00  0.000000
```

Comment: Awesome! That works.  I also want to find the minimum value of random data and add it to A1 like min('Randomdata')+A1 and add this as a new column.  Any suggestions?

Comment: `df.assign(Average=d.mean(1), Stddev=d.std(1), WeirdCol=df['Random data'].min() + df.A1)`  You should know that we like new questions for this sort of thing.  It is more opportunity to earn rep.